# Hide element if MySql query return false using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am having trouble hiding elements if the query returns false.

I have a form for which I want to check if the email address is already on record.

I have here the checkMail.php

```
include("../config.php");
$db = new Database();

$email = $_POST['company_email'];


$query = "SELECT company_email FROM sic_auth WHERE company_email='$email'";
$result = $db->ExecuteQuery($query);
$ecount  =  count($result);

return $result[0]['company_email'];
```

What I want to achieve is to show the class if the email is found and hide it if not found.

```js
// --- Check email Availability for successful adding of employee --- //
function checkMailStatus() {
  // alert("came");
  var company_email = $("#company_email").val(); // value in field email
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'checkMail.php',
    data: {
      company_email: company_email
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == false) {
        // alert(data);
        document.getElementById("submit-form").disabled = true;
        $("#err-text").text("This email is already exists.");
        $('#company_email').addClass('err-input');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<label for="company_email" id="email-err">Company Email address <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" onblur="checkMailStatus()" name="company_email" id="company_email" value="a@b.com" placeholder="Email" required>
<i class="input-helper"></i><span id="err-text"></span></label>
```

Comment: And what is the problem? I would not mix DOM and jQuery access: `$("#submit-form").prop("disabled",!data); $("#err-text").text("This email already exists.").toggle(!data);$('#company_email').toggleClass('err-input',!data);`

Comment: Why not return `{ "exists": true}`  and test `data.exists` instead of `data==false` ???

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan, I can't figure out why it still doesn't work.  I applied your first suggestion.  and instead of data==false I just put (data). what is happening right now is, whatever the result is it always displays the "This email already exists."

Comment: Look in the console in the network tab. What EXACTLY is the PHP returning. Then test that. For example if you return `{"exists":"true"}` then you need to test `data.exists === "true"` since it is a string

Comment: apologies @mplungjan I am not that familiar with this. can you show me where to put the {"exists":"true"}?

Comment: Please keep in mind that your SELECT query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked. Also, is this a PHP problem or a jQuery problem?

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase this is jQuery problem since my query is working my only problem is I can't  make display an element if the email is found and.or hide it if the email is not yet in the system. I only use jQuery occasionally when its only needed like now that's why I am not realy that familliar with it.

Comment: @SleepWalker mplungjan is asking you to check what is returned by your PHP script. `{ "exists": true }` was just an example of a potential return value. We don't know what exactly your PHP outputs, in order to know if you're testing for the correct value or not in your jQuery code.  You seem to be testing for `false`, but from looking at the PHP it would seem that it's most likely to either return an email address - or possibly it will throw an error cases where the email doesn't exist in the database and therefore no row is returned from the query, but your PHP code tries to read it anyway!

Comment: ...so I'd say there's a chance your problem is related to PHP _and_ jQuery - PHP not checking properly if a row was returned from the query, and jQuery not checking for something that PHP is actually likely to output

Comment: following @mplungjan's suggestion, I added, "exists":"true" inside data: right below the company_email: company_email, then added the data.exists === "true" inside if(data.exists === "true"). then I run sample. after that, I check in devTools, from NETWORK tab I see checkMail.php then PAYLOAD tab, it displays, company_email: email123@gmail.com & exists: true.

Comment: Ok. So then you should also 1) remove the code which echoes the actual email address, 2) write it to return `{ "exists": false }` instead when the email address doesn't exist.

Comment: Instead of `return $result[0]['company_email'];` you need to do `header("Content-type: text/json"); echo '{ "exists" : '. $ecount > 0 ? "true" : "false" '}';`

Comment: Please don't add updates to the comment section - edit your question to contain all relevant details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

1. Your PHP code is going to throw an error when the email address doesn't exist in the database because your code goes ahead and tries to read the data from the query result, assuming that there always is one - but there won't be a result row if there wasn't a matching email in the table.
2. Your JS code looks for whether PHP ever returns `false` in order to decide what to do, but your PHP won't ever do that - as above it'll either return the email address or an error message.

As well as fixing the logic bug in the PHP, one way to return the result data in a more structured way is to use JSON. This means you can return a specific value with a name to describe it, and you have the option to return other data items in the same object (or list) as well if you need to.

You should build JSON reliably by first creating a PHP object/array with the structure you want, and then converting it to a JSON string using `json_encode()`.

PHP:

```
//at the start of your script, write
header("Content-type: text/json");

/*....then as per your existing code ... until */

$ecount  =  count($result);

$output = ["exists" => ($ecount > 0 ? true : false)];
echo json_encode($output);
```

JS:

```
success: function(data) {
  if (data.exists == true) {
```

Or for this particular purpose you can return a simple string value instead:

PHP:

```
$ecount  =  count($result);
return ($ecount > 0 ? "yes" : "no")
```

JS:

```
success: function(data) {
  if (data == "yes") {
```